# SharePoint Online File Sharing - 404 Error

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sharing files using SharePoint Online Modern Experience

When I Share a link to a document in SharePoint, and then move the file to a new/different folder, the user can still use the link and can access the files.

But when I Share a link to a mp4(video file), and then move the video file to a different folder the user gets a 404.

Why is this different?

Has anyone experienced something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Files handled by Office Online have an identifier that allows you to move the item yet continue to keep that item tracked with a previously used URL. This is called a Durable Link. This feature applies to Office documents but not MP4s.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - I thought Durable link works only when we activate Document ID feature..

Answer (score 0):

When you create a document, the document generates a document ID, and share a link actually finds the file through this document ID.

So even if you move the file to another library, the user can still find the file through the URL because the document ID has not changed.

But the MP4 file doesn't generate the document ID, so you get 404 errors when you move the file.

Comment: Thanks @Binggo_MSFT 
In my case the document ID feature is not activated, so i am wonder how does SPO generate a doc ID when  doc id feature is not activated on the SC